# JCrop when use set select option the plugin broken

Tags: javascript, jcrop

When i use set select option in JCop , i can't change the selection area , the plugin broken, because i couldn't retrieve ui property to get the handler for image.

Here's the code that i work on :

jsfiddle.net/k_shadow/ng5ayq93/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle it by selecting image by their Id ,you should do it by replacing this line

var $this = this.ui.holder; by this one : $('#original') and get the height and width for the image , this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside `showCoords` point to `window`, so `this.ui` does not exist and when you try to get `this.ui.holder` you get an error inside Jcrop changes handler.

So your changes handler breaks plugin.

Comment: Ok i know that , so what i should i use to get the ui?

Comment: You ask why Jcrop does not work – you have an answer. I don’t know what you should do to ‘get ui’, whatever it means.